# React: Component setState called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when i run my react code.

The code here is based on the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#completing-the-game) provided by React.org

I'm new to react so I i didn't find it easy debugging the code.

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. 
This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or 
componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

This is caused by the `handleClick` method

Error:

```
handleClick
c:/dev/tic-tac-toe/src/index.js:38

  35 |  handleClick(i) {
  36 |    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
  37 |    squares[i] = 'X';
> 38 |    this.setState({squares});
     | ^  39 |  }
  40 | 
  41 |  renderSquare(i) {

renderSquare
c:/dev/tic-tac-toe/src/index.js:45

  42 |   return (
  43 |     <Square 
  44 |       value={this.state.squares[i]}
> 45 |       onClick={this.handleClick(i)} 
     | ^  46 |     />
  47 |   );
  48 | }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the event handler and calling it at the same time.
You could probably do:

```
return (
  43 |     <Square 
  44 |       value={this.state.squares[i]}
> 45 |       onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)} 
     | ^  46 |     />
  47 |   );
```

Comment: It works. but i dont quite get the `bind(this, 1)` part. Do you mind explaining it bit for me. Thanks @Mindastic

Comment: Check this, please: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind
Basically it creates a new function and sets `this` and optional parameters to it.